# Animated resizing of a Grid with Material UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui, transition

I'm playing around with Material UI (Creative Tim's theme) and got stuck at this... I have a `<Grid>` with two `<GridItem>`s inside. One of the (the left one) is the "primary" one, whereas the right one appears occasionally. My question is how to animate the right ones appearing?

So far I have this:

```js
<Grid>
 <GridItem
   md={isViewDetailsMode ? 7 : 10}
   className={classes.collapsible}>
    {...}
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem 
   md={4} 
   className={isVisible ? classes.visible : classes.hidden}>
    {...}
  </GridItem>
</Grid>
```

```css
classes.collapsible: {transitionDuration: "0.3s"}
classes.visible: {transitionDuration: "0.3s"}
classes.hidden: {display: "none"}
```

It sorts of works, but as the left one is shrinking, the right one appears beneath the left one and after the transition is finished it takes its place on the right.

Any suggestions? [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-firefly-4ftfy) is a CodeSandBox.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like columns total more than 12 on CodeSandbox -- first column is 7, second is 4 and spacing is 2. Whenever I adjust the numbers down, column 1 shrinks and column 2 appears next to it.

Comment: Here is how appears for me for a brief second, before aligning right - https://i.imgur.com/OTVbO2T.png

Comment: hey, did you able to improve the animation? I'm looking for the similar feature. In my case, I'm trying to make right column to appear and to be the same (responsive) size as the left one